# Multi store: define a store as canonical

Tags: magento-1.8, multistore, seo

I have a Magento 1.8 multi store installation. Each store is installed in a sub folder (`www.mydomain.com/`, `www.mydomain.com/paris/`, `www.mydomain.com/nimes/`) and contains the same products with different stock values.

With such an install, I have a lot of duplicate content: `www.mydomain.com/product1.html` and `www.mydomain.com/paris/product1.html` are showing duplicate content.

That's why I'd like to define a store as canonical and have pages from other stores point to the corresponding page on the main store.

Any suggestion on how to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved my goal by using an observer to modify the canonical links for category and product pages of stores in subfolders:

```
class Fkoessler_Canonical_Model_Observer
{

  public function coreBlockAbstractToHtmlBefore($observer)
    {
        $block = $observer->getBlock();

        if ($block instanceof Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head) {

            $url = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
            if (Mage::registry('current_product')) {
                $url = Mage::registry('current_product')->getProductUrl();
            } else if (Mage::registry('current_category')) {
                $url = Mage::registry('current_category')->getUrl();
            }
            $block->removeItem('link_rel', $url);

            $url = str_replace('/paris', '', $url);
            $url = str_replace('/niort', '', $url);
            $url = str_replace('/nimes', '', $url);

            $block->addLinkRel('canonical', $url);
        }
    }
}
```